# Why do all arguments except the first one get ignored?

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying to make a custom command prompt. For example, if I type in

```
. filename.sh 1 hello 2 hi 3 a 0 b
```

the custom prompt should look like this:

```
[b][hello][hi][a]$
```

Number 1 stands for second position and number 2 stands for the third position etc. But when I run it, somehow only the first part is shown, like this:

```
[][hello][][]$
```

And I can't overwrite it. For example, when I type

```
. filename.sh 2 hi
```

it should be `[][hello][hi][]$` but instead, it becomes `[][][hi][]$`. How can I solve it?

```
#!/bin/bash

#$1 [$2] $3 [$4] $5 [$6] $7 [$8]

PS1="[][][][]$"

for i in "$*"
do

    #$1
    if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
    then
        PS1="[$2][][][]$"
    elif [ $1 -eq 1 ]
    then
        PS1="[][$2][][]$"
    elif [ $1 -eq 2 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][$2][]$"
    elif [ $1 -eq 3 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][][$2]$"


        #$3
    elif [ $3 -eq 0 ]
    then
        PS1="[$4][][][]$"
    elif [ $3 -eq 1 ]
    then
        PS1="[][$4][][]$"
    elif [ $3 -eq 2 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][$4][]$"
    elif [ $3 -eq 3 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][][$4]$"


        #5
    elif [ $5 -eq 0 ]
    then
        PS1="[$6][][][]$"
    elif [ $5 -eq 1 ]
    then
        PS1="[][$6][][]$"
    elif [ $5 -eq 2 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][$6][]$"
    elif [ $5 -eq 3 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][][$6]$"

        #7
    elif [ $7 -eq 0 ]
    then
        PS1="[$8][][][]$"
    elif [ $7 -eq 1 ]
    then
        PS1="[][$8][][]$"
    elif [ $7 -eq 2 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][$8][]$"
    elif [ $7 -eq 3 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][][$8]$"
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't treat the arguments as a single word. Iterate over the arguments two at a time.

```
# You can do something simpler with an array, but I'm deliberately keeping
# this POSIX-compatible.
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    pos=$1

    case $pos in
      0) v0=$2 ;;
      1) v1=$2 ;;
      2) v2=$2 ;;
      3) v3=$2 ;;
      *) printf 'Illegal slot %d' "$pos" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
    shift
done

PS1="[$v0][$v1][$v2][$v3]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `for i in "$*"`, the value of `i` is the string `1 hello 2 hi 3 a 0 b`, so the loop is executed just once.

Even if you made sure that your loop gets run more than once, you'd still end up with a prompt where only one of the fields is set; all assignments to `PS1` only set one field.

You have to build it dynamically, for example like this:

```sh
# Make sure PS1 is empty
unset PS1

# As long as we see command line parameters
while (($#)); do
    # Set array element at index of first parameter to value of second parameter
    arr[$1]=$2

    # Drop current parameters
    shift 2
done

# Iterate over array and build PS1
for i in {0..3}; do
    PS1+="[${arr[i]}]"
done

# Unset array so it doesn't stick around in environment
unset arr

PS1+='$'
```

In use:

```
$ . prompt.bash 1 hello 2 hi 3 a 0 b
[b][hello][hi][a]$
```

Or with just one element provided:

```
$ . prompt.bash 3 X
[][][][X]$
```